# Setting Jquery as the welcome pages for a Jersey REST service using Grizzly Server

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, rest

I created a Jersey REST service with a Grizzly server.

I do make ajax calls in my jquery and it works on localhost:9998

```
public static final URI BASE_URI = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(9998).build();


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SelectorThread threadSelector = startServer();
    System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
            + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...",
            BASE_URI));
    System.in.read();
    threadSelector.stopEndpoint();
}
```

2 Questions:

1) How would I set the index.html (jquery) as the welcomepage so that when I go to localhost:9998/example/, the index.html would be displayed? (I'm using grizzly so no web.xml)

2) How would I make this visible outside of localhost??

Thanks!!!!!
Any Help would be appreciated!

Comment: this questions is very broad. 1) you need a webserver?! 2) what do you mean? on the web? cloud? your own server?

Comment: Sorry if the question is broad as I am still new to this. My goal is to make this site avaialable to everyone on my domain (localhost). I know I have to create a webserver, but I wanted to start off by displayed my jquery frontend when going to localhost:9998